# The existence of $y$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

For a real-valued $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ function with $f(0)\neq0$. $f'$ is strictly increasing from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ as $x$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Prove that for any $x \neq 0$, there exists $y$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Intuitively I think it must be a $y$ for this convex function such that
$$\frac{f(x+y)-f(y)}{x} = \frac{f(x)}{x}$$
by considering its slope. But I don't know how to prove it in a rigorous way. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Please give your thoughts on why you think so?

Comment: Doesn't $y=0$ work?

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^2$ seems to satisfy the hypothesis, but the only solutions are those where $y = 0$.

Comment: sorry there is a typo, should be $f(0) \neq 0$

Comment: @learnmore well basically my idea is to pick a point $(x,f(x))$ on graph, and I got a line segment between $(0,0)$ and $(x,f(x))$. Then I can shift this line (without rotation) such that it meets the graph at two ends. I think this can be guaranteed by the behavior of $f'$. But that's just my intuition, so I am looking for a rigorous proof.

Comment: @Nullhoz : Did you see my answer? If you feel it has gaps/its wrong let me know. Otherwise can you please close the question by accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $x$ and consider $g_x(y) = f(x+y) - f(x) - f(y)$.

$g_x$ is monotonically increasing for $x > 0$ and monotonically decreasing for $x <  0$. WLOG, assume $ x > 0$ and $f(0) > 0$.

$g_x(0) = -f(0) < 0$ and $$\lim_{y \to \infty}g_x(y) = \lim_{y \to \infty}(f(x+y) - f(y)) -f(x) = \lim_{y \to \infty} \int_{y}^{x+y}f'(t)dt - f(x) = \infty$$

(As, $f'$ is increasing from $-\infty$ to $\infty$)

By the usual arguments of continuity, there exists $y > 0$ such that $g_x(y)=0$

(The other cases can be approached similarly)

Comment: Very nice argument. Rather than taking a limit, it suffices to say that $g_x(y) = \int_y^{y+x} f'(t)\,dt - f(x) > x\, f'(y) - f(x)$, and is positive whenever $f'(y) > f(x)/x$, which happens for some $y$ since $f'$ is strictly increasing to $\infty$. It took me a minute to see that, if $f(0) < 0$, you need to consider $y$ going toward $-\infty$.

Comment: Yes! Thanks. My arguments however can be extended to any function with $f'$ increasing and positive at some point and negative at some other point.